# How do I replace missing value with values from another column in R

Tags: r, na

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
ID var1 var2 var3
per1 1 NA 3
per2 3 NA 5
per3 NA 4 6
per4 4 7 9
per5 7 NA NA
per6 NA 8 NA
```

I want to replace the missing values from column 2 (var1) with values from column 3 (var2), but only if the values from var1 are missing. So the output should look like this:

```
ID var1 var2 var3
per1 1 NA 3
per2 3 NA 5
per3 4 4 6
per4 4 7 9
per5 7 NA NA
per6 8 8 NA
```

I would think that something like this would work:

```
df$var1[is.na(df$var1)] <- df$var2
```

But unfortunately it doesn't, I get the following error message:

```
Warning message:
In df$var1[is.na(df$var1)] <- df$var2.2 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You also have to subset the var2-elements, for example `df$var1[is.na(df$var1)] <- df$var2[is.na(df$var1)]`

Comment: Great, thank you! If you post this as an answer, I can accept it and give you your credits :)

Comment: Less 'brackety' solution using `dplyr`: `df %>%
  mutate(var1 = if_else(is.na(var1), var2, var1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
df$var1[is.na(df$var1)] <- df$var2[is.na(df$var1)]
```